# Converting foreach loop to make compatible with Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, loops

I have the following for each loop:

```
function trackMeasurementChanged() {
                var weightInputs = document.querySelectorAll('[id*="HeightAndWeight_Weight"]');

                weightInputs.forEach(function(input) {
                    input.addEventListener('input', function(input) {
                        changedMeasurements.push("weight");
                    })
                });     
            }
```

This isn't supported in Internet Explorer and is failing some unit tests so I am trying to convert the syntax to the following:

```
      for (var i = 0, len = weightInputs.Length; i < len; i++) {
                    var input = weightInputs[i];
                    console.log(input);
                    input.addEventListener('input', function (input) {
                        changedMeasurements.push("weight");
                    })
                }
```

^ That is my attempt at least, but now the code does not work. There's no error, just the "weight" string is no longer pushed into the array. Please can anyone point out where I have gone wrong? I am not familiar with the older syntax.

Comment: Use the [polyfill](https://gist.github.com/bob-lee/e7520bfcdac266e5490f40c2759cc955)

Comment: You wrote `weightInputs.Length` with "L" uppercase